# Unity: Hide material in specific area

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shaderlab

I am making a 3D application for ios and Android.

Each object in the below image has a different material than others.

[image]

I want to make the part of object 3 that intersects with object 2 **appears** and the part that intersects with object 1 **disappears**.

**Notes:**

Object 3 is moving up and down.

The 3 objects have the same depth from the camera (same z).

Comment: What do you mean by "part of object x" ? Geometry ? Sub objects ?

Comment: each object has no sub-objects. I think it is geometry

Comment: Maybe with stencil buffer, or shaders,

Comment: Do you have and example for something similar to what I am searching for?

Comment: I made something in that area using shaders. This should point you in a direction: https://www.ronja-tutorials.com/2018/08/06/plane-clipping.html.

Comment: Are you using Sprites or 3D-Models? When using Sprites have a look at [SpriteMasks](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html)

Comment: I am using 3D-models.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own shaders in Unity's ShaderLab using Cg/HLSL and use stencil buffers. [Unity's manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html) gives you the basics, while a good practical introduction can be found [here](https://www.ronja-tutorials.com/2018/08/18/stencil-buffers.html).

In short, stencils allow you to enable/disable rending in the clip space, based on reference values of other shader passes. A caveat is that the values are global and all shaders can read and write in the buffer, so you should carefully choose a reference value.